# sharepoint rest api sitecollections

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, odata

I use the following API

> https://.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='(contentclass=STS_Site)'&rowlimit=500

for getting the site collection, but it seems to miss site collections.
for example :
It misses

> https://.sharepoint.com/sites/sep

.
But for which I have all permissions.
Even using the following api I was able to access the site

> https://.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='(path=https://.sharepoint.com/sites/sep)'

and checked

> content class is STS_Site

P.S: It didn't cross the row limit
what is wrong with my API. Or else is there is any REST API for getting only site collections.

Thanks & Regards,
Sai Monesh C S

Answer (score 0):

If you have created the site pretty soon, then you might have to wait till it is crawled. Have you tried this query?

https://(yourorg).sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='(contentclass=STS_Site AND path=https://(yourorg).sharepoint.com/sites/sep)'

Comment: What if I don't know the path and all I want is sitecollection.Also this is one of the old site collection